# TabHost add tabs dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a `TabHost` and I want to create tabs dynamically. I have looked at many examples but they are not working.

```
TabHost tabHost;
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();
TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
tab1.setIndicator("First Tab");
tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class));
tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

This is the last thing that I have tried but it does not work. Here is some links that I have considered. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

[Example1](http://android.attemptone.com/layouts/dynamic-tabs/)

[Example2](http://android3school.blogspot.com.tr/2012/08/android-tabhost-example-code.html)

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.LH.tabletres.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Why not working? give me brief information

Comment: @Blast I suggest you should switch to ActionBar Tabs now.

Comment: I have no idea. There are banch of errors in android stuido when I tried to run it. 
Some of these here 

 `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`
 `at com.LH.tabletres.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)`
 ` at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)`

Line:18 includes `tabHost.setup();`

Comment: @Blast show your layout, `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @nikis I have added activty_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to set `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` to your `tabhost`. like below

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >........
.....
</TabHost>
```

Comment: `tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);` throws an error.

Also http://android.attemptone.com/layouts/dynamic-tabs/ in this link they used like `android.R.id.tabhost`

Comment: I have tried it. I have set id and changed code as `R.id.tabhost` still not working :/

Comment: @Blast you just need to set this id `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` in your `TabHost`.that's it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write

```
<TabHost
   android:id="@+id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   ........
 </TabHost>
```

so change `@android:id` to `@+id`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false">

            </TabWidget>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

```
    final TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

        spec1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return (new AnalogClock(MainActivity.this));
            }
        });
        spec1.setIndicator("Clock");
        tabs.addTab(spec1);
    }
```